# PostgreSQL, Django: what index to create for STRICT_WORD_SIMILARITY filtering queries?

Tags: django, postgresql

PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT id, company_id, ticker, title, STRICT_WORD_SIMILARITY('wm', public.company_codetickertitle.title) AS title_similarity 
FROM public.company_codetickertitle 
WHERE STRICT_WORD_SIMILARITY('wm', public.company_codetickertitle.title) > 0.39;
```

I already have GIN and GIST indexes on the `title` field, however I see that PostgreSQL is performing a seq scan.

How can I get it to scan the index instead?

Django code:

```
CodeTickerTitle.objects.annotate(
title_similarity=TrigramStrictWordSimilarity(search_input, "title"),)
.filter(title_similarity__gt=0.39)
.only("ticker", "title", "company")
```

Comment: To use the pg_trgm index, you would need to set  pg_trgm.strict_word_similarity_threshold to 0.39 and then use the <<% operator, rather than the function.  I don't know how to get Django to write it that way, though.